# Half donut chart with apexcharts

Tags: charts, apexcharts

I am trying to make half donut chart with multiple data as following picture using `apexcharts`
[image]

So far I only found `Semi Circle Gauge` with single data as in their [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/radialbar-charts/semi-circle-gauge/), and when I insert more data into `series` , it doesn't come out as I want. Is there any ways to achieve this ? You can see my code sandbox sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/apex-charts-sgbjf?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Check this: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/pie-charts/semi-donut/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the angles as shown below to create a semi donut

```js
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90
  }
}
```

[image: apexcharts-semi-donut]

This feature is available since v3.22.2

Comment: Awesome ! I will be looking forward to use it in the next release. I will accept answer once I get to test it and see if it works well.